# pjax losing the rails javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

I have some javascript below which loads upon first page load, but then get lost by pjax.

Any way to solve this pls? I just have pjax running on the  in application.html file so should i make it less aggressive or is there some js magic that will hold my js code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#note_label_tokens").tokenInput("/labels.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    prePopulate: $("#note_label_tokens").data("pre"),
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the JS into a function, and then call it on `document.ready` and when the `end.pjax` event is fired.